# Random white crosses appearing on items in Internet Explorer

Tags: windows-8.1, internet-explorer

In Internet Explorer 11 on Windows 8.1 Pro x64, I am getting crosses behind almost every site I go on. This does not happen on Firefox or Google Chrome. Why is this happening, and how can I fix it?

Specs:
 - Windows 8.1 Pro
 - Intel HD Graphics 4600
 - Intel Core i5 4460

[image: Image 1]

---

[image: Image 1]

---

[image: Image 3]

Comment: I've heard of this issue before. To solve it you need to update your display adapter so that it is compatible with IE11.

Comment: @zain.ali I have the latest display adapter driver from the Acer website

Comment: Okay, have you tried resetting IE?

Comment: @zain.ali Yes, I have

Comment: Try disabling  add-ons if you have any. Then close IE and see if the issue still occurs.

Comment: @zain.ali I have done that, and I have tried reinstalling Windows

Answer (score 0):

Try "Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering*"

Comment: Internet Options > Advanced > Use software rendering instead of GPU rendering*"

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: Take a look at this as might help: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie11-iewindows8_1/ie11-win-81-white-cross-on-background-of-images/7db8bc7d-28ce-4f8f-be9a-0e3ae469923f